# How to match string format in Regex c#

Tags: c#, regex, string

I am passing a correct string formate but its not return true.

```
string dimensionsString= "13.5 inches high x 11.42 inches wide x 16.26 inches deep";
 // or 10.1 x 12.5 x 30.9 inches
 // or 10.1 x 12.5 x 30.9 inches ; 3.2 pounds

Regex rgxFormat = new Regex(@"^([0-9\.]+) ([a-z]+) x ([0-9\.]+) ([a-z]+) x ([0-9\.]+) ([a-z]+)( ; ([0-9\.]+) ([a-z]+))?$");
if (rgxFormat.IsMatch(dimensionsString))
{
     //match
}
```

I can't understand whats wrong with code ?

Comment: Your regex does not match several words after the number. See https://regex101.com/r/q8XJIB/2 where I just doubled each `" ([a-z]+)"`. However, what are the pattern requirements? Is the number of words fixed?

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew  there is  10.1 x 12.5 x 30.9  this pattern are fixed but, some time added string after number (2 word or more than 2 also possible).You suggestion is correct for 2 word string but if come more than ? like "13.5 inches high x 11.42 inches wide test x 16.26 inches deep";

Comment: Replace them with `(.*?)`. Try `^([0-9.]+) (.*?) x ([0-9\.]+) (.*?) x ([0-9.]+) (.*?)( ; ([0-9.]+) (.*))?$`, see [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/q8XJIB/4).

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew  Thanks . its working perfectly fine :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pattern only accounts for single words after  the numbers. Allow any number of symbols there (with `.*` or `.*?`) to fix the pattern:

```
^([0-9.]+) (.*?) x ([0-9\.]+) (.*?) x ([0-9.]+) (.*?)( ; ([0-9.]+) (.*))?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/q8XJIB/4).

Note that the last `.*` is used with a greedy quantifier since it is the last unknown bit in the string (to match all the rest of the string). The `.*?` are non-greedy versions that match as few occurrences of any char but a newline as possible.

Replace regular spaces with `\s` to match any kind of whitespace if necessary.

Comment: sure, I will. its really help.